# Raspberry Pi 3b+ - Turning off power LED from /boot/config.txt no longer works with kernal 5.15.56-v7+

Tags: kernel, apt, config.txt, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, power-light

I successfully turned off all my LEDs on my Raspberry Pi 3B+ [according to this guide](https://smarthomescene.com/guides/how-to-disable-leds-on-raspberry-pi-3b-4b/), by adding these lines in the `/boot/config.txt`:

```
[all]
# Turn off Power LED
dtparam=pwr_led_trigger=none
dtparam=pwr_led_activelow=off
# Turn off Activity LED
dtparam=act_led_trigger=none
dtparam=act_led_activelow=off
# Turn off Ethernet ACT LED
dtparam=eth_led0=14
# Turn off Ethernet LNK LED
dtparam=eth_led1=14
```

I then rebooted and all the LEDs were off as desired.

However I've now updated all my packages with `apt update` and `upgrade` which also upgraded the kernal after a reboot. The newly updated kernal is `5.15.56-v7+ #1575`

Since this update of my system and kernel, the power (red) LED on my Pi remains on even though it was turned off before the upgrade.

I've even tried additional reboots but the red power led remains on.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: I think it is more likely the firmware, which was updated at the same time as the kernel, is responsible for this.

Comment: I've submitted a [bug report](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/1742) for this. I don't know if anything will be done; I seem to recall that in the past, `they` have disavowed support for control of the power led.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - I seem to recall that the firmware controlling the Power (red) LED is prone to change. Perhaps the [bug report](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/1742) will get this fixed eventually, or perhaps it won't?

In either case, the `sysfs` interface still works, even though it's been *deprecated* for over 2 years. Here's a couple of ways to turn off the power (red) LED:

#### 1. Turn Power LED OFF at boot time using `cron`:

Because `root` privileges are needed to write to `sysfs`, you should use the `root crontab`:

```bash
$ sudo crontab -e
# root's crontab opens for editing in your default text editor...
# add the following line: 

@reboot /usr/bin/echo '1' > /sys/class/leds/led1/brightness 

# save, exit the editor & reboot your system to verify
```

Note that this is easily extended to turn the LED ON & OFF at specified times; e.g. ON during the day, OFF at night.

#### 2. Turn Power LED OFF (or ON) from the command line:

You can use the same command used in the `root crontab`, but you'll first need to `su` to `root`. If you prefere to use `sudo` instead, you can use the `tee` command instead of the *redirect* ( `>` ) to accomplish this:

```bash
$ echo '1' | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/led1/brightness  # OFF
```

If you wish to turn the Power LED ON:

```bash
$ echo '0' | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/led1/brightness  # ON
```

If you wish to read the status of the Power LED:

```bash
$ cat /sys/class/leds/led1/brightness
```

Which can be used in a *script* to check and/or change the Power LED state:

```bash
$ if [ $(cat /sys/class/leds/led1/brightness) == '0' ]; then echo "ON"; else echo "OFF"; fi;
```

#### 3. Use the ***revised*** device tree configuration to extinguish the Power LED:

Some *interim*(?) responses to the [Aug 21 bug report](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/1742) suggest that a revised `dtparam` configuration will extinguish the Power LED on the following newer models:

- Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+
- Raspberry Pi 4 Model B
- Raspberry Pi 400
- Raspberry Pi Compute Module 4

For these models, the revised `dtparam` configuration to extinguish the Power LED is:

```
dtparam=pwr_led_trigger=default-on
dtparam=pwr_led_activelow=off
```

Comment: Thanks for the update, and apologies for taking so long to accept your answer, I was locked out of my account.

Comment: @SneakyShrike: No worries, and thanks for following up.

Answer (score 1):

This is already fixed. As per [a comment in the bug report](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/1742#issuecomment-1230978826) that Seamus shared in his answer, you have to remove:

```
dtparam=pwr_led_trigger=none
```

Summarizing, you only need the following to turn the power and activity LEDs off (tested in an updated Raspberry Pi 4):

```
# Disable the PWR LED
dtparam=pwr_led_activelow=off
# Disable the Activity LED
dtparam=act_led_trigger=none
dtparam=act_led_activelow=off
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem after updating. As a workaround for now I'm just using:

```
echo 1 > /sys/class/leds/led1/brightness
```

Answer (score 0):

Pi 3 Model B bullseye - actually /sys... location changed. To turn off:

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/PWR/brightness
```

or put this in your root crontab:

```
@reboot echo 0 > /sys/class/leds/PWR/brightness
```

Answer (score 0):

`sudo nano /boot/config.txt`

There is currently a [different way](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/1742#issuecomment-1230978826) to achieve this on different pi models.
You may want to add [model filters](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/config_txt.html#model-filters) to config file as followingly:

```
#Disable Power LED (Red)
[pi3]
dtparam=pwr_led_trigger=none
[pi3+]
[pi4]
dtparam=pwr_led_trigger=default-on
[all]
dtparam=pwr_led_activelow=off

#Disable Activity LED (Green)
dtparam=act_led_trigger=none
dtparam=act_led_activelow=off
```

`sudo reboot`